# Angular 9 Ivy template type check 'Object is possibly 'null''

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-ivy

Basically i have 2 components. [Repository](https://github.com/Zaixu/angular-first-second)

```
  <kendo-datepicker #first [max]="second.value"></kendo-datepicker>
  <kendo-datepicker #second  [min]="first!.value"></kendo-datepicker>
```

That brings this error on serving the application:

ERROR in src/app/app.component.ts:7:37 - error TS2531: Object is possibly 'null'.

```
7   <kendo-datepicker #second  [min]="first.value"></kendo-datepicker>
```

Each uses the other. Which i assume is why the error comes, since one is not defined while the other is made. But it is allowed to have null. 
This worked in Angular 8, but converted to 9 and no longer.

How can i make it ignore this particular case?

- I can't change the date picker.
- Changing the tsconfig 'fullTemplateTypeCheck' is not a viable option either.
- Would prefer a simple solution that would not begin to use form events. I did find in the ivy migration, that i could use '!' non-null assertion operator, but i have not been able to get that to work in this case

Comment: Does using ? Instead of ! do anything different

Comment: @Phix Unfortunately not.

Comment: Looks like i can use $any(first).value
Would wish there was another way but cant seem to find one.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's saying `value` can be null - and therefore this is what is happening:

You're trying to set an input null **on the kendo control** which may not be updated for ivy - check their blog / make sure you're using their 'ivy-friendly' version (if available).

1) There is an option specifically to disable this check on `@Inputs`

[`strictNullInputTypes`](https://angular.io/guide/template-typecheck)

OR

2) Try the `!` after `[min]="first.value"`